# Firebase Email Link with Nav Compose

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Firebase authentication flow where the user is asked to confirm his/her email to finish its authentication phase. It's an email link process.

So far, I've successfully managed to redirect the link to the right screen in the application with a NavGraphBuilder.

My question for now is: according to the documentation, I need to **Verify link and sign in** the user, but how should I configure the arguments for the path of the composable at that entry point so I can fetch the received data?

```
    composable(
            route = "...",
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink {
                    uriPattern = "https://<APPLICATION_ID>.firebaseapp.com"
                    action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                }
            )
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("..."){
                    type = ...
                    defaultValue = ".."
                }
            )
        ){...}
``
```

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: Thanks, but it won't. The email link method open the application by an Intent, which then uses the data received to compare against the email saved in the device storage, to only then confirm the account creation.